# Custom horizon (5 months) with FullCalendar Timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm working on a project where I have to create some particular views on FullCalendar 5 in timeline with React.

The idea is to display more or less long periods with duration slots per month.

Generally, the horizons will be by 6 months, but I can't find how to make custom views with a precise horizon (Ex: 01 April - 31 August).

I thought it was possible by defining a start + a duration, but obviously no way to do it dynamically, because the user must be able to change the horizon when needed.

Did I miss an option to do this? Or is FullCalendar really not made for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying you want the user to be able to pick two dates and have the calendar make a timeline showing everything between those two precise dates? Have you tried using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange ?

Comment: The horizons will be defined in advance, but they can change horizon, so yes. 
I didn't know that visibleRange was able to handle this with a timeline, I'll look into it... Thanks

Comment: As far as I know it works across all views, but yes it would be good to test

Answer (score 3):

Make a custom view with 5 month duration, add the button to the header:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  customButtons: {
    resourceTimelineSixMonths: {
      text: 'resourceTimelineSixMonths',
      click: () => {calendar.changeView('resourceTimelineSixMonths')},
    },
  },
  headerToolbar: {
    left:   'title',
    right:  'prev,today,next resourceTimelineSixMonths',
  },
  initialView: 'resourceTimelineSixMonths',
  views: {
    resourceTimelineFiveMonths: {
      duration: { months: 5 },
      type: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    },
  },
};
```

You can tell the calendar what date to start on: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialDate

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialDate: '2022-09-28',
};
```

You can also play with adding this to the `calendar` object:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  visibleRange: {
    start: '2022-09-23',
    end: '2023-02-23',
  },
};
```